# XSL to group XML

Tags: xslt

Am sure this is really easy, but banging my head at moment.
I am trying to implement Group By in XSL by using the Muenchian Method.  However the examples I have read all look to be on 2 nodes, I need it on multiple ones.  So I have tried amending the code but am failing at moment...
My XML is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<KBBCONNECTJOB>
<OGOODS>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>Base End Support Panel  Natural Oak</NAME>
    <POS>1</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Highline Integrated Dishwasher Fascia</NAME>
    <POS>2</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Highline Base Unit</NAME>
    <POS>3</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Highline Integrated Fridge/Freeezer Fascia</NAME>
    <POS>4</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM 3 Drawer Pan Unit</NAME>
    <POS>5</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Highline Base Unit</NAME>
    <POS>6</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>500MM Highline Base Unit</NAME>
    <POS>7</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Fridge/Freezer Housing Unit - Type 6</NAME>
    <POS>8</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>600MM Double Oven Housing Unit - Type 2</NAME>
    <POS>9</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>2650 Plinth Natural Oak Inc Seal Strip</NAME>
    <POS>10</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>Worktop 600 Single P/F 4000 Black Brazil</NAME>
    <POS>11</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>30MM Bullnose Sq Cornice 3600MM Natural</NAME>
    <POS>12</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>10Mtr Roll Edging Tape Natural Oak</NAME>
    <POS>13</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <CODE>ET03</CODE>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>Schock Stnd Inset 1.5 Bowl  Drainer Sink</NAME>
    <POS>14</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>90</SUPP>
    <WHAT>1</WHAT>
    <NAME>Schock Universal Plumbing Kit 1.5 Bowl</NAME>
    <POS>15</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - Integrated Combination Fridge/freezer 70/30 A+ Rated</NAME>
    <POS>1</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - Integrated Washing Machine</NAME>
    <POS>2</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - Double Oven Bi Aa Rated Main Oven Touch Control Clock S/steel</NAME>
    <POS>3</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - Five Burner Front Control 70cm Gas Hob Wok Ffd Stainless Steel</NAME>
    <POS>4</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - 70cm Chimney Extractor Hood - Stainless Steel</NAME>
    <POS>5</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <SUPP>130</SUPP>
    <WHAT>3</WHAT>
    <NAME>CDA - Fully Integrated Dishwasher 60 Cm A++Aa Rated</NAME>
    <POS>6</POS>
    <ORDERNO>2204</ORDERNO>
  </Row>
</OGOODS>
</KBBCONNECTJOB>
```

I need it in format

```
order
    what
        supp
           name what pos ordercat

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<order display="2204">
  <productgroup display="Kitchen Units">
    <supplier display="supplier 1 from lookup">
      <product display="Base End Support Panel  Natural Oak" what="1"pos= "1" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Highline Integrated Dishwasher Fascia" what="1"pos= "2" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Highline Base Unit" what="1"pos= "3" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Highline Integrated Fridge/Freeezer Fascia" what="1"pos= "4" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM 3 Drawer Pan Unit" what="1"pos= "5" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Highline Base Unit" what="1"pos= "6" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="500MM Highline Base Unit" what="1"pos= "7" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Fridge/Freezer Housing Unit - Type 6" what="1"pos= "8" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="600MM Double Oven Housing Unit - Type 2" what="1"pos= "9" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="2650 Plinth Natural Oak Inc Seal Strip" what="1"pos= "10" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="Worktop 600 Single P/F 4000 Black Brazil" what="1"pos= "11" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="30MM Bullnose Sq Cornice 3600MM Natural" what="1"pos= "12" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="10Mtr Roll Edging Tape Natural Oak" what="1"pos= "13" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="Schock Stnd Inset 1.5 Bowl  Drainer Sink" what="1"pos= "14" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="Schock Universal Plumbing Kit 1.5 Bowl" what="1"pos= "15" ordercat="D" />
    </supplier>
  </productgroup>
  <productgroup display="Appliances">
    <supplier display="Supplier 2 from lookup">
      <product display="CDA - Integrated Combination Fridge/freezer 70/30 A+ Rated" what="3"pos= "1" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="CDA - Integrated Washing Machine" what="3"pos= "2" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="CDA - Double Oven Bi Aa Rated Main Oven Touch Control Clock S/steel" what="3"pos= "3" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="CDA - Five Burner Front Control 70cm Gas Hob Wok Ffd Stainless Steel" what="3"pos= "4" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="CDA - 70cm Chimney Extractor Hood - Stainless Steel" what="3"pos= "5" ordercat="D" />
      <product display="CDA - Fully Integrated Dishwasher 60 Cm A++Aa Rated" what="3"pos= "6" ordercat="D" />
    </supplier>
  </productgroup>
</order>
```

The order number will always be the same, but the other parts could all be same WHAT, or all from the same SUPP, or each row could be different.

My current XSL which partially works is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:key name="level0" match="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row" use="ORDERNO" />  <!-- group -->
    <xsl:key name="level1" match="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row" use="concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT)" />  <!-- group by WHAT -->
    <xsl:key name="level2" match="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row" use="concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP)" />   <!-- group by WHAT and SUPP -->
    <xsl:key name="level3" match="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row" use="concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP, '|', POS)" />   <!-- group by WHAT and SUPP and POS to get the lines -->
    <xsl:key name="level4" match="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row" use="concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP, '|', POS, '|', NAME)" /> 


    <xsl:template match="/KBBCONNECTJOB">
        <xsl:for-each select="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row[count(. | key('level0', ORDERNO)[1]) = 1]">
            <order>
                <xsl:attribute name="display">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ORDERNO"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:for-each select="/KBBCONNECTJOB/OGOODS/Row[count(. | key('level1', concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT))[1]) = 1]">  <!-- get the WHAT groups -->
                    <xsl:sort select="WHAT" />                      

                    <productgroup>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('level3', concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP, '|', POS))">
                            <xsl:variable name="lookup_what" select="WHAT"/>
                            <xsl:attribute name="display">
                <!--                <xsl:value-of select="document('./Lookups/lookup_specialsmap.xml')/data/kbbproducttab[@what=$lookup_what]/type"/>  -->
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <supplier>
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('level4', concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP, '|', POS, '|', NAME))">
                                    <xsl:variable name="lookup_supp" select="SUPP"/>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="display">
    <!--                                    <xsl:value-of select="document('./Lookups/lookup_suppliers.xml')/data/kbbsupplier[@code=$lookup_supp]/k8suppliercode"/>   -->
                                    </xsl:attribute>

                                    <product>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="key('level4', concat(ORDERNO, '|', WHAT, '|', SUPP, '|', POS, '|', NAME))">

                                            <xsl:attribute name="display">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="what">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="WHAT"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="pos">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="POS"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="ordercat">
                                                <xsl:text>D</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </product>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </supplier>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </productgroup>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it isn't giving me multiple rows for the product display part.  I have remmed out a part that looks off to get a lookup from another file, this is working in production.

I am happy to change methods if there is an easier one...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A full XML view of the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Have added the desired outcome to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Locks like you are quite close.
Your first for-each group the rows by `ORDERNO`. 
Your second for-each should only consider the rows which already selected by the firs for-each. 
Therefor put your current `ORDERNO` into a variable.  and use the levle0 key in the second for-each.

```
<xsl:variable name="onr" select="ORDERNO" />
<xsl:for-each select="key('level0', $onr)[count(. | key('level1', concat($onr, '|', WHAT))[1]) = 1]">  <!-- get the WHAT groups -->
                <xsl:sort select="WHAT" />
```

Follow this concept for the deeper loops.
Attention: This is a xslt 1.0 Muenchian grouping solution. But your stylesheet says 2.0. Therefore there are other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for reply and help.  Will try it out and see how I get on.  (Out of office at moment).